# DHCP-Enabled Router Sometimes Won't Talk to Host with Static IP

Tags: ip, dhcp, tcpip, static-ip, dhcp-server

I have a Windows 7 host connected to a router running DD-WRT. The router is running a DHCP server.

For reasons I don't need to detail here, I have set a static IP on the host, as opposed to configuring a static IP reservation for that host in the router.

The IP is within the range of IPs the router is configured to hand out, it is not reserved, and it is not in use by any other host.

I have noticed that sometimes the host and the router can talk, and sometimes they can't. I haven't been able to characterize when they can and cannot talk.

Is this just an idiosyncracy of the combination of implementations I'm using? Or is there something in the RFCs that states that if a router offers DHCP, it should ignore hosts it did not give a lease to, even if the IP the host is using is valid and available?

UPDATE 4/12/2016
Well, I had a chance to do some digging, and DHCP servers are required to interoperate with statically-configured hosts (RFC 2131, page 6).

I seem to be narrowing my situation down. It seems that if a host is assigned an address by DHCP and I then statically assign that IP to that same host, the host and the router can talk fine for a while, but at some point they quit talking.

I suspect, but have not yet verified, that they quit being able to talk when the lease expires. But since the IP address is now statically assigned, the host has every right to use it, and it seems the "interoperability" rule would indicate that the router (i.e. the DHCP server) should continue to talk to the host.

So, I am still trying to figure out if my router is non-compliant or if I still do not have the full picture of required behavior.

Comment: Some firewalls have such a blocking option, but to the best of my knowledge dd-wrt does not do this.

Comment: It should be pointed out that it is also just bad practice to assign a static IP address that falls within a DHCP scope's range and not have it reserved via MAC address, regardless of whether another device is using that IP address or it is just "unassigned and available" in the DHCP pool.... In general, it is recommended to assign a static IP address outside of the DHCP scope's range,

Comment: Yes, it would be bad practice for a permanent setup. I can't take the time to explain my reasons (complicated / not point of original post), but this is temp to work through complex config issues (outside of DHCP).